# How to get Height of the object like Google Measure App using scenform

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am developing an app where I need to get the height of the object but still not able to figure out what's the best way to achieve this. I have done the coding to get the length and breadth but not for the height measurement.

I did one approach but it failed i.e, On HitResult Anchor created. I was scaling a transformable node and getting it size after scaling to that point but that way failed.

Please help me into this

Answer (score -1):

Fine a plane close to object. Find feature points (PointCloud) on the top of your object and from a point

```
val height = point.y - selectedFloor.pose.ty()
```